# What color does beamer use as default color?

Tags: beamer, color

[image]

I am trying to figure out what color beamer is using as default for "Hello World!"

Here is a list of colors: http://latexcolor.com/

Looks like Blue (Pigment) but I'm not so sure.

Comment: `\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.7}$`

Comment: What theme are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the file `beamercolorthemedefault.sty` you can find the color definition:

```
\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.7}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=beamer@blendedblue}
```

and the `structure` color is used, for example, in

```
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure}
\setbeamercolor{title}{parent=titlelike}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\definecolor{foo}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.7}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Color here}\large
\color{foo}Color here defined by hand
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```